# Exhaustively parse file for all matches

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a grammar for parsing some log files using pyparsing but am running into an issue where only the first match is being returned. Is there a way to ensure that I get exhaustive matches? Here's some code:

```
from pyparsing import Literal, Optional, oneOf, OneOrMore, ParserElement, Regex, restOfLine, Suppress, ZeroOrMore

ParserElement.setDefaultWhitespaceChars(' ')
dt = Regex(r'''\d{2} (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) 20\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d\,\d{3}''')
# TODO maybe add a parse action to make a datetime object out of the dt capture group
log_level = Suppress('[') + oneOf("INFO DEBUG ERROR WARN TRACE") + Suppress(']')
package_name = Regex(r'''(com|org|net)\.(\w+\.)+\w+''')
junk_data = Optional(Regex('\(.*?\)'))
guid = Regex('[A-Za-z0-9]{8}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{4}-[A-Za-z0-9]{12}')

first_log_line = dt.setResultsName('datetime') +                    \
            log_level('log_level') +                                \
            guid('guid') +                                          \
            junk_data('junk') +                                     \
            package_name('package_name') +                          \
            Suppress(':') +                                         \
            restOfLine('message') +                                 \
            Suppress('\n')
additional_log_lines = Suppress('\t') + package_name + restOfLine
log_entry = (first_log_line + Optional(ZeroOrMore(additional_log_lines)))
log_batch = OneOrMore(log_entry)
```

In my mind, the last two lines are sort of equivalent to

```
log_entry := first_log_line | first_log_line additional_log_lines
additional_log_lines := additional_log_line | additional_log_line additional_log_lines
log_batch := log_entry | log_entry log_batch
```

Or something of the sort. Am I thinking about this wrong? I only see a single match with all of the expected tokens when I do `print(log_batch.parseString(data).dump())`.

Comment: `Optional(ZeroOrMore(expr))` is the same as just plain `ZeroOrMore`, just slightly more inefficient. And I think a parse action to convert your `dt` to a Python `datetime` makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scanString` behavior is a strong clue. Suppose I wrote an expression to match one or more items, and erroneously defined my expression such that the second item in my list did not match. Then `OneOrMore(expr)` would fail, while `expr.scanString` would "succeed", in that it would give me *more* matches, but would still overlook the match I might have wanted, but just mis-parsed.

```
import pyparsing as pp

data = "AAA _AB BBB CCC"

expr = pp.Word(pp.alphas)
print(pp.OneOrMore(expr).parseString(data))
```

Gives:

```
['AAA']
```

At first glance, this looks like the `OneOrMore` is failing, whereas `scanString` shows more matches:

```
['AAA']
['AB']  <- really wanted '_AB' here
['BBB']
['CCC']
```

Here is a loop using `scanString` which prints not the matches, but the gaps between the matches, and where they start:

```
# loop to find non-matching parts in data
last_end = 0
for t,s,e in expr.scanString(data):
    gap = data[last_end:s]
    print(s, ':', repr(gap))
    last_end = e
```

Giving:

```
0 : ''
5 : ' _'  <-- AHA!!
8 : ' '
12 : ' '
```

Here's another way to visualize this.

```
# print markers where each match begins in input string
markers = [' ']*len(data)
for t,s,e in expr.scanString(data):
    markers[s] = '^'

print(data)
print(''.join(markers))
```

Prints:

```
AAA _AB BBB CCC
^    ^  ^   ^
```

Your code would be a little more complex since your data spans many lines, but using `pyparsing`'s `line`, `lineno` and `col` methods, you could do something similar.

Comment: Many thanks, these are very good tips. I'll find some time to look into this today.

Comment: A major issue (possibly not the only one...) seems to be that I'm looking for a tab character in my stack trace lines (`Suppress('\t')`) but never setting `.parseWithTabs()` on any elements. So there's one bit of debugging done.

Comment: `parseWithTabs` only needs to be set at the top level expression, along with `parseString`.

Comment: Instead of detecting additional lines by matching on a TAB, you could look for lines that *don't* start with a timestamp: `additional_log_lines = ~dt + package_name + restOfLine`

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a workaround that seems to do the trick. For whatever reason, `scanString` *does* iterate through them all appropriately, so I can very simply get my matches in a generator with:

`matches = (m for m, _, _ in log_batch.scanString(data))`

Still not sure why `parseString` *isn't* working exhaustively, though, and still a bit worried that I've misunderstood something about pyparsing, so more pointers are welcome here.

Comment: The 3-tuple returned by `scanString` contains the matched tokens, the match's start location and the match's end location. Perhaps by looking at the gap between the first match's end and the second match's start might give a clue as to what is causing your `parseString` call with `OneOrMore` to fail.